# Appropriate averaging for program runtimes on different samples

Tags: data-visualization, mean, descriptive-statistics

I'm trying to figure out which "average" and "deviation" statistics are most appropriate for [a software benchmark I'm creating](http://chriswarbo.net/projects/theory-exploration).

For background: I am benchmarking programs whose task is to read in a given set of 'definitions' written in some programming language (e.g. a `plus` function, a `sort` function, etc.), and after some amount of time halt and output some 'conjectures' about those definitions (e.g. `plus` is commutative, `sort` is idempotent, etc.).

I have a reasonable (IMHO) method to measure the "quality" of the output, using precision and recall against a ground truth corpus, but I'm unsure how to most appropriately aggregate the run times.

In my approach I have a corpus with ~400 definitions, and I'm sampling 30 subsets of size 1, 30 subsets of size 2, and so on up to size 20 (anything larger and the programs become infeasibly slow). I chose 30 since it's a rule of thumb for avoiding 'small sample statistics'; in particular, as a *separate* analysis to my current question, I want to allow comparison between different programs using a paired difference test, and 30 samples should be enough to justify using a paired Z-test rather than a Wilcoxon signed-rank test.

Back to my current question: for each subset, we run the program *once*, with a timeout of 1 hour. I want to combine these 30 runtimes to get an "average" and a "spread" for each sample size, to see how the program "scales" as the size increases. In *theory*, all programs I'm testing are exponential time; but this may not hold empirically, due to various confounding factors I would like to subsequently explore.

At the moment I am considering using the median to report the "average value" and the mean absolute deviation (MAD) to report the "spread around the average". This is because the 'go-to' statistics of mean and standard deviation don't seem representative, given the highly non-normal distribution of my data.

For example, here are the runtimes of one program for 30 samples of size 5. The y axis is logarithmic, and shows runtime in seconds. The x axis of the top graph is in the order that the data were obtained, the bottom graph shows the same data but in a shuffled order (I used these graphs to eyeball whether the results appear independent, e.g. to ensure they weren't getting faster over time due to caching, or other such effects).

[image: Example of runtimes for sample size 5]

So my questions are:

- Do median and MAD seem reasonable, given my data and my goals?
- Does my *approach* seem reasonable? Perhaps it's more appropriate to consider these as 'survival times'? I also considered 'fitting a power law' to normalise the data, but this seems problematic due to the dominance of large values, which are also those with the sparsest data.

Comment: It's not fully clear to me what your goals are. What will you do with your summary statistics? If you want to assess reliability, you may want to look at quantiles instead.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I want to see how the time varies according to the "size". I think you're right about quartiles, and am now thinking that a box plot may be appropriate, with one box per "size".

Comment: I personally prefer beanplots or violinplots to boxplots - they give more information and are less easily misinterpreted.

Comment: I'm graphically upset by bars on a log scale, but that aside, no summary obviously will do justice to a situation in which wild values occur intermittently; the medians may be resistant but it's the tail that I would care about as a software user (or indeed programmer). The reciprocal of a time is (proportional to) a speed; the data may allow summary that way. Timeout of 1 hour may be standard terminology in your field, but what does it mean for any data analysis?